# Alternative ways to enter English letters in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, login, keyboard-layout

I don't know how but the English layout was removed from Ubuntu. At the moment I can't log in, because my password contains English letters. Also, when I'm starting it in advanced mode as root, I still can type only Russian letters and can't execute any command. So I'm trying to find any way to log in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be placed at askubuntu.com and there is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514284/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-layout-on-login-screen) available.

Comment: It is not the same, I can't type a command in the terminal, only Russian available

Comment: It's not clear that it's the same question because _this_ question does not give enough information.  It does not say whether this is TUI or GUI login.  If it is GUI login, it does not say what happens with TUI login.  It does not say the version of Ubuntu, which could be 10 years old for all that we know.  It does not say whether the machine is networked and SSH is available, or (very unlikely but possible) has a serial port.  It does not say whether the questioner applied (systemd's, again presuming an unstated Ubuntu version) rescue or emergency modes at bootstrap and what happened if so.

Comment: It is about any input. GUI and TUI. Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3. SSH is not set up.